# Full height Right div

Tags: php, html, css, html4

i want my div to be of 100% height

[image]

HTML & CSS codes

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="content-box news-box" style="float: right">news section</div>
    <div class="content-box slider-box" style="height: 150px;">slider box</div>
    <div class="content-box plan-box">plan box</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-box{
    background-color: #d54515;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.news-box{
    width: 19.5%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slider-box{
    width: 79%;
}

.plan-box{
    width: 79%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the JSFiddle setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `position:absolute; right:0` to `.news-box` and position:relative to parent div

Remove floats

```
 .wrapper{
    border:solid green 1px;
    position:relative
 }
 .content-box{
    background-color: #d54515;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: height: 100%;
 }
 .news-box{
    width: 19.5%;
    height: 100%;   
    position:absolute;
    right:0    
 }
 .slider-box{
    width: 79%; 
 }
 .plan-box{
    width: 79%;
    margin-top: 20px;
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pzp5a/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Height on your div container :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-box news-box" style="float: right">news section</div>
    <div class="content-box slider-box" style="height: 150px;">slider box</div>
    <div class="content-box plan-box">plan box</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS Code :

```
.content-box{
    background-color: #d54515;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.container{
    height: 200px;    
}

.news-box{
    width: 19.5%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slider-box{
    width: 79%;
}

.plan-box{
    width: 79%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xkZ49/